# How to select elements from dropdown in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How to select elements from dropdown in selenium webdriver?

```
driver.get("http://www.terna.it/SistemaElettrico/TransparencyReport/Load/Dayaheadloadforecast.aspx");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        Actions a = new Actions(driver);

    String Year = "2015";

    //WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("dnn_ctr5826_TernaViewDocumentView_cbAnno_Input"));
   // WebElement tab_down = driver.findElement(By.id("dnn_ctr5826_TernaViewDocumentView_cbAnno_DropDown"));
    a.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("dnn_ctr5826_TernaViewDocumentView_cbAnno_DropDown"))).sendKeys("2015").click();

    search_fn.setClickyear();
```

HTML CODE:

```
<input name="dnn$ctr5826$TernaViewDocumentView$cbAnno" type="text" class="rcbInput radPreventDecorate" id="dnn_ctr5826_TernaViewDocumentView_cbAnno_Input" value="2019" readonly="readonly" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: Hi, please: add description of what you what you want to do, what you are doing and what results do you get, and add a reproducible example if possible. Otherwise, this question is complete gibberish and not answerable.

Comment: Which _element_ from which **dropdown**?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a usual dropdown. You need to work with it as with List which contains web elements. In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53627449/how-to-select-particular-location-from-the-drop-down-list-which-is-initiated-dyn/53627717#53627717) I described how to work with this kind of drop-downs.